# Synfony2 : Joint tables just take one id

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have two joint tables in Synfony2 : "query" and "result". The table query save the research of the user and the table result save the results of the research. I would like to set in the table result the corresponding id of the research but right now when I set my data to result it creates a lot of lines in query (and don't just take the corresponding id). 
Here is my code to be more spectific:

My entity Query:

```
class Query
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string\NotBlank()
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="query", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $query;
```

My entity Result:

```
class Result
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="author", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="website", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $website;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Biblishare\BiblishareBundle\Entity\Query", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $query;
```

And my controller :

```
$html7 = $this->container->get('simple_html_dom');
        $html7->load($result7);

        // Create DOM from String
         $html7 = str_get_html($result7);
        // Find all article blocks
         foreach($html7->find('.result-item-metadata') as $article7) {
         if(isset($article7->find('.rw a', 0)  ->plaintext))
         {
            $item7['title'] = $article7->find('.rw a', 0)  ->plaintext;
        }
        elseif(isset($article7->find('.title a', 0)  ->plaintext))
        {
            $item7['title'] = $article7->find('.title a', 0)  ->plaintext;
        }
        else
        {
        }

         if(isset($article7->find('.contrib a', 0)  ->plaintext)) 
         {
            $item7['auteur'] = $article7->find('.contrib a', 0)  ->plaintext;
         }
         else
         {
            $item7['auteur'] = '';
         }

         if(isset($article7->find('.rw a', 0)  ->href)) 
         {
            $item7['url']     = 'http://www.jstor.org' . $article7->find('.rw a', 0)  ->href;
         }
         elseif(isset($article7->find('.title a', 0)  ->href)) 
         {
            $item7['url']     = 'http://www.jstor.org' . $article7->find('.title a', 0)  ->href;
         }
         else
         {
            $item7['url'] = '';
         }

         $resultat7[] = '<div class="float_checkbox"><input class="result_scrap" type="checkbox" name="choix[]" value="<a href=\''.$item7['url'].'\' class=\'result_title\' target=\'_blank\'>' . $item7['title'] . '</a></span></br><span class=\'result_author\'> ' . $item7['auteur'] .'</span>" /><span></span></div><label for="choix">' . '<a href="'.$item7['url'].'" class="result_title" target="_blank">' . $item7['title'] . '</a></span></br><span class="result_author">' . ' ' . $item7['auteur'] .'</span></label>';

         $result->setTitle($item7['title']);
         $result->setAuthor($item7['auteur']);
         $result->setUrl($item7['url']);
         $result->setWebsite('jstor');
         $result->setQuery($query);
         $em->persist($result);
         $em->flush();
         $em->clear();
        }
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you are having troubles getting it to work the way you want you can try specifying on both sides like [this mentions](http://ormcheatsheet.com/#association).  The first example is what you are looking at.  Once you get it working you can back it off from there.  Getting a firm understanding of what is actually happening with those annotations is key.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, actually I think I'm not wrong about the ORM mapping. The problem is that I persist and flush my data in a loop and so the line $result->setQuery($query); is in the loop too... It creates one query line for each result line and I would like just one query line with one id for all the result lines...